# Using Form.Bookmark to test if a search is successful seems to affect the search itself

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am implementing a Search facility in my application that will be better integrated with the UI than the standard Access search facility.  When the user invokes the search facility (keystroke, menu or ribbon) a pop-up non-modal form opens for them to specify search parameters:

[image: Search form]

The LookIN combo is populated with the names of all the visible fields on the form to be searched plus an option for "All fields" if there is more than one field on the form.

When the user clicks Find Next, the following code runs in the appForm class module:

```
Private WithEvents myForm As Access.Form 'Set elsewhere in the class module to point to the form to be searched

Private Function ISearchHandler_ActionFindNext(strFindWhat As String, intMatch As Integer, booMatchCase As Boolean, intSearchDirection As Integer, booFormatted As Boolean, strField As String, booFindFirst As Boolean) As Boolean

' Params  : Are set according to the options selected by the user on the search form
'Returns true if search was successful otherwise false

        2610     On Error GoTo PROC_ERR

                 Dim intScope As Integer            
                 Dim strOldBookmark As String
                 Dim strNewBookmark As String

                 ISearchHandler_ActionFindNext = False 'Assume failure

        'Set the focus to the form to be searched, which may be a subform or a pop-up form

                 If HasParent(myForm) Then 'HasParent tests whether the form is a sub-form
                    myForm.Parent.SetFocus 'Handle sub-form
                 Else
                    myForm.SetFocus 'Handle pop-up form
                 End If

        2620     If strField <> "All fields" Then
        2630         myForm.Controls(strField).SetFocus 'Set the focus to field to search
                     intScope = acCurrent
                 Else
                    intScope = acAll 'Leave the focus on the forms ActiveControl
        2640     End If

        'Perform the search and determine if it was successful

                 strOldBookmark = myForm.Bookmark 'Bookmark current position
        2650     DoCmd.FindRecord strFindWhat, intMatch, booMatchCase, intSearchDirection, booFormatted, intScope, booFindFirst 
                 strNewBookmark = myForm.Bookmark 'Bookmark new position
                If StrComp(strNewBookmark, strOldBookmark, vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then 'Current record hasn't changed
                    DisplayMessage strFindWhat & " was not found."

                 Else
                    ISearchHandler_ActionFindNext = True
                 End If

        PROC_EXIT:
        2670     Exit Function

        PROC_ERR:
        2680     Select Case Err.Number
                     Case Else
        2690             LogError
        2700     End Select
        2710     Resume PROC_EXIT
        2720     Resume

             End Function
```

The search functionality works as expected if I replace this section of the code:

```
             strOldBookmark = myForm.Bookmark 'Bookmark current position
    2650     DoCmd.FindRecord strFindWhat, intMatch, booMatchCase, intSearchDirection, booFormatted, intScope, booFindFirst 
             strNewBookmark = myForm.Bookmark 'Bookmark new position
            If StrComp(strNewBookmark, strOldBookmark, vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then 'Current record hasn't changed
                DisplayMessage strFindWhat & " was not found."

             Else
                ISearchHandler_ActionFindNext = True
             End If
```

with

```
        2650     DoCmd.FindRecord strFindWhat, intMatch, booMatchCase, intSearchDirection, booFormatted, intScope, booFindFirst 

                 ISearchHandler_ActionFindNext = True
```

i.e. if I remove the tests to see if the search was successful using the form's bookmark.  The focus moves to the expected field, and successive use of the Find Next button finds the search string repeatedly until there are no more to be found.

If however, I include the Bookmark tests, the search always fails -- debugging shows that the focus goes to the right place, but the search string isn't found, the current record doesn't change and the failure message is displayed.

Using Google, I've not been able to find anything that explains to me what is happening here. Should this work, and if so, what am I doing wrong?  (Once I've got this working, I also need to introduce a test to see if the activecontrol has changes as well, to cater for searches across all fields, but one step at a time...)

For clarity, the test data includes the word being searched for in multiple fields in multiple records, and multiple times in some fields.

**Update**: If I set booFindFirst to always be False (i.e. start the search at the record after the current one) the code works. If I set to to be True, the code fails.